# What will be the regex to select the videoUrl property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

On a scraping problem, I am stuck with regex.

here is on what I am trying to use regex to get 3 videoUrl.

```
"mediaDefinitions": [
    {
        "defaultQuality": false,
        "format": "mp4",
        "quality": "720",
        "videoUrl": "https:\/\/examplesite.com\/videos\/08\/720P.mp4?hash=ZSWTc8RdZ06z6VIipZBo%2BVtCaog%3D"
    },
    {
        "defaultQuality": true,
        "format": "mp4",
        "quality": "480",
        "videoUrl": "https:\/\/examplesite.com\/videos\/08\/480P.mp4?hash=o8gUG%2BoDwZWzhi4rQpItuBwBzpM%3D"
    },
    {
        "defaultQuality": false,
        "format": "mp4",
        "quality": "240",
        "videoUrl": "https:\/\/examplesite.com\/videos\/08\/240P.mp4?hash=urfqwGzQXPvhHQiGLhhrztYYZIA%3D"
    }
],
```

To get the `videoUrl` what I tried was `/("videoUrl":).+(%3D")/g`
as regex pattern to match but then it just gave me the long string from first  `"videoUrl":` to the third  `%3D"`.

my code was

```
const regex = /("videoUrl":).+(%3D")/g;
let matches = string.match(regex);
```

Where am I going wrong?

I want 3 of these url separately.

Comment: Why are you scraping instead of calling `JSON.parse`?

Comment: what I gave there is a snapshot of a large script that has multiple objects, I could not just simply `JSON.parse`, it will give me syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `.+` section is greedy, and will continue to match characters until it can't do so any more. Hence, it matches all to the last `%3D` substring.

You can make a regex greedy by adding a `?` after the quantifier.

Additionally, I would invert the capture blocks, as you seem to be most interested in getting the video url. Hence, I would suggest:

`/"videoUrl": (.+?)%3D"/g`

link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/MKtd8E/1

Comment: Thank this turns out to be a perfect solution. actually, from your solution, I can do this ```"videoUrl":(| )"(.+?)"``` and i dont need to depend on the last %3D. again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a regex solution, do the following:

`"videoUrl":\s*"(\S*)"`

The only capturing group will contain the desired URL. All I am doing is capturing all the non-whitespace characters within double quotes after skipping the term `"videoUrl"` along with any whitespaces that follow.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqHTeG/1)

Comment: sometimes it turns out that videoUrl does not end with %3D but with". so in those cases, it needs some more modification. Thanks, It still helped me to understand exclusion.

Comment: The above regex doesn't depend on the URL ending with `%3D` or anything else for that matter